# Loading PHP code with ajax when scrolling to the bottom of page - not working on iPhone

Tags: php, ajax

I have my ajax which says when the user gets to the bottom of the page, it loads a PHP script. On iPhone it loads the same one multiple times (it loads id #5, then will continually load id #4 over and over - on PC it loads id #5 through to id #1.)

index.php - AJAX

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var loadLogs = 0;

      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'inc/loadLogs.php',
        data:{
          'offset': 0,
          'limit': 1
        },
        success: function(data){
          $('#showAuditLogs').append(data);
          loadLogs += 1;
        }
      });

      $(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
          $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'inc/loadLogs.php',
            data:{
              'offset': loadLogs,
              'limit': 1
            },
            success: function(data){
              $('#showAuditLogs').append(data);
              loadLogs += 1;
            }
          });
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
```

index.php - HTML

```
<div id="showAuditLogs">

</div>
```

loadLogs.php

```
<?php

  include 'database.php';

  $limit = $_GET['limit'];
  $offset = $_GET['offset'];

  $logs = DB::query("SELECT * FROM auditlog ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $limit OFFSET $offset");
  foreach($logs as $l){
    $action = $l['action'];
    $logId = $l['id'];
    echo "<p class='card-text'><strong>$logId </strong>$action</a></p><hr style='background-color: white;'>";
  }

?>
```

Comment: Just taking a guess here but you might want to try debouncing the scroll event handler ~ https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function

Comment: @Phil I am not actually too good with ajax, and I just watched youtube to get this, was hoping you may be able to show me how to do this with my code?

Comment: Stop using user input in a query. Use prepared statements. (search sql-injection)

Comment: how come I can't just get an answer to my question? I didn't come here looking for something to do with sql injection - how ever thank you for that and I will take a look before I release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to create an element like a button that load the script when you click on it, then use this code to trigger the button when you're scrolling to the bottom (working on all devices) :

```
var CheckIfScrollBottom = debouncer(function() {
    if (getDocHeight() == getScrollXY()[1] + window.innerHeight) {
        $('your button id or class').trigger('click');
    }
});
```

Your ajax will be :

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var loadLogs = 0;
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'inc/loadLogs.php',
      data:{
        'offset': 0,
        'limit': 1
      }
      ,
      success: function(data){
        $('#showAuditLogs').append(data);
        loadLogs += 1;
      }
    }
          );
    var CheckIfScrollBottom = debouncer(function() {
      if (getDocHeight() == getScrollXY()[1] + window.innerHeight) {
        $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: 'inc/loadLogs.php',
          data:{
            'offset': loadLogs,
            'limit': 1
          }
          ,
          success: function(data){
            $('#showAuditLogs').append(data);
            loadLogs += 1;
          }
        }
              );
      }
    }
                                       );
  }
                   );
  document.addEventListener('scroll', CheckIfScrollBottom);
  function debouncer(a, b, c) {
    var d;
    return function() {
      var e = this,
          f = arguments,
          g = function() {
            d = null, c || a.apply(e, f)
          }
      ,
          h = c && !d;
      clearTimeout(d), d = setTimeout(g, b), h && a.apply(e, f)
    }
  }
  function getScrollXY() {
    var a = 0,
        b = 0;
    return "number" == typeof window.pageYOffset ? (b = window.pageYOffset, a = window.pageXOffset) : document.body && (document.body.scrollLeft || document.body.scrollTop) ? (b = document.body.scrollTop, a = document.body.scrollLeft) : document.documentElement && (document.documentElement.scrollLeft || document.documentElement.scrollTop) && (b = document.documentElement.scrollTop, a = document.documentElement.scrollLeft), [a, b]
  }
  function getDocHeight() {
    var a = document;
    return Math.max(a.body.scrollHeight, a.documentElement.scrollHeight, a.body.offsetHeight, a.documentElement.offsetHeight, a.body.clientHeight, a.documentElement.clientHeight)
  }
</script>
```

Comment: How do I incorporate this into my code may I ask? Sorry I am not too good with ajax

Comment: tell me first, your code is working on other devices ? so the ajx code is working right ?

Comment: It works on Windows, but on iPhone it doesn't. Haven't tried on android.

Comment: check the answer again